# authentication AWS method Rest DSL

Tags: json, rest, oauth-2.0, apache-camel, jax-rs

I have a question regarding **Restful services**

I need to upload CSV files to an AWS server.  I am registered with account. 
First I need to obtain an access token and use that to upload the files. I have not coded anything yet, trying to understand the best approach, I so hope to use Camel-Rest-DSL. It is required to communicate with JSON. But, the authentication part has me stuck, I’m pretty sure it uses OAuth2 auth, RestFul web service and JSON, this should just be a client, I was looking at WSS4J for JAX-RS OAuth2 but I don’t know.

I’ve done it with postman, this is the scenario. The username and password are fictional

```
    *Get Access Token  
                    uses POST verb
                    requires Token Request URL
    uses Basic Auth  requires Username = Client ID of tenant ( needs to be encoded base64 )
    HEADER parm Content-Type = x-www-form-urlencoded
    Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                   'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded Client ID
    Access Token body - grant_type, username, password
    Body = username = 5c0642fe-a495-44db-93f7-67034556fa2c061_ingestor
                    password = 154f0252d166f27b5e21ef171b03212a79f41a0daf3
                    grant_type = password

    #returns the access_token as JSON

    POST or upload files
    uses POST verb
    requires Ingestion URL UploadURL

    UploadURL=https://apm-ts-query-svc-prd.app-api.aws-usw02-pr.something.io/v2/time_series/
    UploadFolder=upload
    headers = 
    key Authentication  "Bearer + access Token" (from request access token above)
    key Tenant = TenantUUID
    key X-GE-CsvFormat = ODB

    # Body
    form-data
    key file=file
    # POST DATA
    headers content-type application/json
                   authorization: "" + token
                   tenant: "" + tenant
```

**My environment**

Jboss Fuse  6.3-310

Karaf version               2.4.0.redhat-630310

JVM
  Java Virtual Machine        Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM version 25.162-

b12
  Version                     1.8.0_162
  Vendor                      Oracle Corporation

Operating system
  Name                        Linux version 2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: Can you try to reformat your question so its a bit more readable and formatted correctly between code vs normal text.

Comment: @ClausIbsen I've done an edit but its pending in queue for peer review... if you have access to such a queue, you can take a look at that (until (if) my edit is approved)

Comment: thank you Claus and Rushikumar, I'm sorry, I'll get it right next time.

Comment: I'm verifying if I can use either the AOuth2, SAML2 or JWT to manage token access with the UAA development team. I may get lucky. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't use OAuth2/SAML assertions so I will simply request a token and cache it and use it later. this is my test code

```
    @Override 
    public void configure() throws Exception { 

        //Configure the Rest Web Service Component transport to use a REST implementation
        restConfiguration() //Configures the REST DSL to use a specific REST implementation
            .component("jetty")         //Specifies the Camel component to use as the REST transport
            .host("localhost")          //The hostname to use for exposing the REST service
            .port("8282")           //The port number to use for exposing the REST service JMX tooling
            .scheme("https")            //The protocol to use for exposing the REST service
            .contextPath("/oauth/token")        //Sets a leading context path for the REST services
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)  //Enables binding mode for JSON 
            .jsonDataFormat("json-jackson")     //Specifies the component that Camel uses to implement the JSON data format
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true"); //set arbitrary properties on the underlying data format component

        //Configure the Rest Endpoint
        rest("/oauth")      //Defines a service using the REST DSL. Each of the verb clauses are terminated by a to() keyword,
                            //which forwards the incoming message to an endpoint 
            .post("/token")
            .produces("application/json")
            .consumes("application/json")
            .type(TokenEntities.class)
            .route()
            .routeId("Get Auth Token Route")
            .autoStartup(true)
            .id("Get Auth Token Service")
            .description("Get Authorization Token")
            .process(new UAARequestTokenProcessor())
            .to("https://d1e53858-2903-4c21-86c0-95edc7a5cef2.pager-uaa.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.pager.io/oauth/token")
            .to("log:logger?showBody=true")
            .to("direct:accessToken")
            .endRest();

        //Define the Route - from() Defines a regular Camel route.
        from("direct:accessToken").to("log:logger?showBody=true"); }

public class UAARequestTokenProcessor implements Processor {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UAARequestTokenProcessor.class);

private String clientId = "myClientID";
private String userName = "myUserName";
private String password = "myPassword";

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        LOG.info("Processing UAA token request for " + clientId + " and " + userName);

        Message msg = exchange.getOut(); //create outbound message exchange

        StringBuilder authHeader = new StringBuilder("Basic ");       
        authHeader.append(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((clientId + ":").getBytes("UTF_8")));

        String body = String.format("grant_type=password&username=%s&password=%s",
                  URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8"), //Translates a string into x-www-form-urlencoded format
                  URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8"));

         msg.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODE");
         msg.setHeader("Authorization", authHeader.toString());
         msg.setBody(body);
    }

}
```